# FBO rendering issue - Using generated FBO color/depth in same App for Drawing using GLSL

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, fbo

[image: **Output With BLIT Call - Test Code**]

[image: **Output Without Using BLIT CALL Test Code**]

**Image with two cubes is when its using BLIT Call - Test Code**

**Image with one Cube is when its not Using BLIT CALL - Test Code**

**Folks,
Please follow the attached pictures & Code as below..**

Struggling with this from last 2 days..

Facing an issue while using FBO in below code, I am able to attach & render to FBo successfully, BUT some how not able to use that as a texture (color & depth buffers) in the same program, MY glReadpixel call after rendering to FBO Shows me all Zero's data...

When generated FBO(color,depth) is used in GLSL- shader code , which is called from Draw2() function displays a blend white cube without texture..

please suggest...,  below is the complete code... , I am creating an FBO & using 2 shaders one for Normal rendering & other one uses the color & depth from FBO processed earlier..

**Here is MY SHADER CODE**

```
        init_gl()
        {
```

**This Fragment Shader Code is for normal rendering used in Program under draw()**

```
            static const char *fragment_shader_source =
                "precision mediump float;           \n"
                "                                   \n"
                "varying vec4 vVaryingColor;        \n"
                "                                   \n"
                "void main()                        \n"
                "{                                  \n"
                "    gl_FragColor = vVaryingColor;  \n"
                "}                                  \n";
```

**This Fragment Shader Code is used in Program2 under draw2()**

```
                static const char *fragment_shader_source2 =
                "precision mediump float;           \n"
                "                                   \n"
                "varying vec4 vVaryingColor;        \n"
                "uniform sampler2D color;       \n"
                "uniform sampler2D depth;       \n"
                "                                   \n"
                "void main()                        \n"
                "{                                  \n"
                "float r = pow(texture2D(color, gl_FragCoord.xy / vec2(256, 256)).a, 128.0); \n"
                "float g = texture2D(depth, gl_FragCoord.xy / vec2(256, 256)).a;\n"
                "float b = pow(texture2D(depth, gl_FragCoord.xy / vec2(256, 256)).a, 128.0); \n"
                "gl_FragColor = vec4(r, g, b, 1.);   \n"
                "}                                  \n";
```

**MY FIRST DRAWING ON FBO**

```
    static void draw(uint32_t i)
    {

            EGL_CHECK(glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)); 
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        EGL_CHECK(glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS));
            EGL_CHECK(glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboInfo.id));
        EGL_CHECK(glUseProgram(program));

        //CUBE DRAWING
```

**Doing Read Pixel here, Its returning all zero's**

```
        GLubyte *pixels = malloc(4 * 256 * 256);
        EGL_CHECK(glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0));
        EGL_CHECK(glReadPixels(0, 0, 256, 256, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels));

            //**TO TEST my FBO , IF ITS HAVING SOME RENDER DATA**
        EGL_CHECK(glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0));
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fboInfo.id); 
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, 256, 256, 0, 0, 256, 256, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
            //TEST CODE ONLY

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboInfo.id);
            glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

        draw2(i);

    }
```

**2nd DRAWING WITHOUT FBO (BUT this uses FRAG SHADER WHICH CAN ACCESS FBO data color,depth)**

```
    static void draw2(uint32_t i)
    {

        glUseProgram(program2);

        //Draw Same Kind of Cube , Which we draw in draw() function

    }
```

**These are the functions to create FBO (color,depth)**

```
         GLuint createTexture2D(const int w, const int h, GLint internalFormat, GLenum format, GLenum type)
            {
                GLuint textureIdX;
                EGL_CHECK(glGenTextures(1, &textureIdX));
                EGL_CHECK(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIdX));

                EGL_CHECK(glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST));
                EGL_CHECK(glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST));
                EGL_CHECK(glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
                EGL_CHECK(glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
                if (GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT == format) {
                    EGL_CHECK(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_NONE));
                    EGL_CHECK(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE, GL_INTENSITY));
                }
                EGL_CHECK(glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, w, h, 0, format, type, 0));
                EGL_CHECK(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));
                return textureIdX;
            }

            int createFBO(void)
            {
                int result = 0;
                unsigned int fb = 0;

                fboInfo.color = createTexture2D(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, GL_RGBA, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);
                fboInfo.depth = createTexture2D(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT);

                EGL_CHECK(glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboInfo.id));
                EGL_CHECK(glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboInfo.id));


                EGL_CHECK(glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboInfo.color, 0));
                EGL_CHECK(glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, fboInfo.depth, 0));

                int data = EGL_CHECK(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
                if (GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE == glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)) {
                    printf("FBO %d set up successfully\n", fboInfo.id);
                    result = 1;
                }
                else {
                    printf("FBO %d NOT set up properly!\n", fboInfo.id);
                }

                EGL_CHECK(glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0));
                return result;
            }
```

**This is how my FBO Struct Looks Like**

```
typedef struct {
    GLuint id;
    GLuint color;
    GLuint depth;
}FBOInfo;
```

**My MAIN function looks a below where I create FBO & then call my draw function & swap the buffers..**

```
            unsigned long i = 0;
            int ret = init_gl();
            ret = createFBO();
            draw(i);
            EGL_CHECK(eglSwapBuffers(eglDisplay, eglSurface));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is quite a lot of code, and you suggested that the problem is with the FBO setup, I focused on that section. I did spot a critical problem in that part of the code where you set up the attachments:

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, fboInfo.depth, 0);
```

If you call `glGetError()` after this, you should see an error returned, because `GL_RENDERBUFFER` is not a valid value for the 3rd argument. The only valid arguments are `GL_TEXTURE_2D` and the `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_*` values. You have to use `GL_TEXTURE_2D` in this case.

It might actually be better to use a renderbuffer for the depth buffer if you never use it as a texture. But to do that, you'll have to use all the corresponding calls:

- Create the id with `glGenRenderbuffers`.
- Bind it with `glBindRenderbuffer`.
- Allocated it with `glRenderbufferStorage`.
- Attach it to the FBO with `glFramebufferRenderbuffer`.

Comment: When I change th enum value & replace it by GL_TEXTURE_2D, I get an Error For FBO Not Setup Properly...